# Octave unexpectedly crashes

Tags: octave

I have a long running octave script, which often runs several hours. Often, at some random point with no specific error line, I am getting this:

```
attempting to save variables to 'octave-workspace'...
save to 'octave-workspace' complete
```

I mean, it is very polite to save all my progress, but it would be even better if it would tell me what the reason is. Also, is there a way to catch these kind of errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which operating system and which Octave version are you using? You can build octave with debugging symbols and run it with gdb.

Are you able to determine the point it stops from the saved octave-workspace workspace? (By having a look at the vars and their contents?)

It would be the best if you are able to create a mall script which reproduces the error and then file a bug report on https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave

Btw, I think it would be better to discuss this on the help mailinglist help@octave.org  than on stackoverflow because it's not a programming problem/question.

Comment: I am using 3.8.2 on Debian Wheezy x64. And you're probably right, the mailing list may be the more suitable place to discuss this.

Comment: On Debian Wheezy Octave is 3.6.2-5. Have you installed Octave from source? In this case see here http://wiki.octave.org/Debugging_Octave howto build with debugging symbols

Comment: No, I installed that version from the backports hoping the error would no longer occur.